# React Router Dom returns a blank page when going to a particular route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

when I am redirecting to a sibling component , the URL is changed in the browser and  there is a blank page that is returned.

when i try to go to the component directly via url still gives a blank page.

**Index.js(Routing is defined here)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import loginComponent from "./loginComponent";
import { AccountComponent } from "./AccountComponent";


class APP extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={loginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/GetAllAccounts" exact component={AccountComponent} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

render(
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <APP />
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

LoginComponent.js(Where the redirection happen,Skipped all the html and validation here since it is not causing any problem.)

```
 Axios.post('http://localhost:49776/api/Home/DoLogin', model, headers)
            .then(result => {
                localStorage.setItem("accounts", result.data);
                console.log(result);
                console.log(result.data);
                this.props.history.push("/GetAllAccounts");
            });
export default withRouter(loginComponent);
```

So After the successful call to the Rest API , it redirects to GetAllAccounts.

AccountComponent

```
import React from "react";
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class AccountComponent extends React.Component {
```

constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { data: [] }
    }
        componentDidMount() {
            alert(localStorage.getItem("accounts"));
            this.setState({ data: localStorage.getItem("accounts") });
        };

```
    render() {
        return (
            <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>OwnerFirstName</th>
                        <th>OwnerLastName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>item.Id</td>
                                <td>item.Name</td>
                                <td>item.OwnerFirstName</td>
                                <td>item.OwnerLastName</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}
```

There is no alert also in the event componentDidMount.

**In the console it says data is not defined,I am setting data like this**

```
componentDidMount() {
        alert(localStorage.getItem("accounts"));
        this.setState({ data: localStorage.getItem("accounts") });
    }
```

I am not able to figure it out whats going wrong here.

Comment: Are you mixing up AccountComponent and AccountDetails?

Comment: @PierreC. I updated the question, it has the right component name also the error in console.

Comment: try using `window.localStorage` wherever you have used `localStorage`. if it runs, i'll explain in the answer

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay no nothing changes, it seems the componentdidmount event never fires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access `data` directly like this. If you set a *state* property named `data`, you have to access it using `this.state.data` in the `render()` function.

```
this.state.data.map(item => {
    ...
});
```

Another issue you might face is that the `componentDidMount` function is triggered after a first render of the component (see [React componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)) which means that you will access data in `render()` before it is created and use `map` on an undefined value.

I suggest you either use `componentWillMount()` or create the data property in a `constructor` like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: [] };
}
```

Comment: So I got the alert of json object from the event. it gives this error now this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: What is the format of your JSON object? `map` can only be used on an array.

Comment: I am sending a List<object> from C#, which is specifically Serialize,in the console i get this  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: That's a weird output. As mentioned in other comments, this data structure problem is not relevant to the original question. You should accept a solution here and create a new one if needed.

Comment: The problem was when i was setting the value in local-storage it was converted into string, So I had to Stringy it before saving and parse once I recieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `componentDidMount` is not firing due to

1. There is an error in the render method. You are using `data.map` and you are setting the data in `this.state.data`
2. There is no validation in the statement itself, because on the first render that variable will have no value. Something like `{this.state.data && data.map(..)}` should be apt in your case.

So, why the method is not firing? It's probably because the execution being sequential, it stops when its encounters an error in your `data.map` statement. Fix those errors and i think you'll be good to go.

Comment: So I have a added a constructor , now the event fires. However when accessing  in the return it fails this.state.data.map is not a function, Why is it so ?

Comment: this error means that your `data` doesn't have any value at the time when this statement was executed. Or your `data` isn't of type `array`. check point 2 @ankur

Comment: From C# I send a List of Object which I Serialize result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts) . For some reason when i do a console.log of result it gives me [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] which is not a valid array for it. I tried to parse it shows it has been already parsed.

Comment: then your error probably lies in the data structure manipulation. which is out of the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

You're making a very small mistake.
Instead of this:

```
    <Route path="/GetAllAccounts" exact component={AccountComponent} />
```

Use this:

```
    <Route path="/GetAllAccounts" exact component={<AccountComponent/>} />
```